# poorer quality and jagged lines issue when rotating camera

Tags: picamera, v4l2, dietpi

I am capturing video from my raspberry pi camera using **v4l2rtspserver**, but I need the image to be rotated 90 degrees. Rotating it makes the image appear to have less resolution and there is an aliasing problem in the image. The thing is, I need the image to be rotated because I can't position the camera module any other way. That could be happening? why is it displayed in poorer resolution? what solutions do I have? Thank you very much.

Command I use to stream the image:

```
v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0
```

Command to rotate the image:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl rotate=90
```

Image 90º:

[image]

Image 0º:

[image]

Aliasing in rotate 90º:

[image]

Comment: The issue appears to be with the software, not the Pi.

Comment: I wish. What could be happening?

Comment: the software is linux related ... your question belongs at a linux site, not RPi site

Comment: my guess is that the `v4l2-ctl` requires more parameters than what you gave it ... it is probably choosing a low-res default for one of the parameters ... again, this is not the site to be asking about it